# how to avoid black screen in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

how to remove black screen and title in phone-gap app.when i enter into the app i'm getting black screen and project title before i get splash screen.please help how to avoid that.

```
<widget id="io.phongap.hello" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>phonegapproject</name>
<description>
    Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
<platform name="android">
     <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png"/>
</platform>

<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">

</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>

<feature name="SplashScreen" >
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />

<param name="onload" value="true" />
```

```
**<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" /> 
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="750"/>
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>**
```

this is screen i get default,after that it is go to slash screen how to i retify that
splash screen
[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWPUs.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

> change your **config.xml** as referenced below :

```
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    id        = "com.domain.app"
    version   = "1.0.0">

    ...

    <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
        <supports-screens 
            android:xlargeScreens="true" 
            android:largeScreens="true" 
            android:smallScreens="true" />
        <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            </activity>
        </application>
    </gap:config-file>
</widget>
```

> and for the Blank Screen,This is an intermediate screen that Android
>   shows while your process is being forked. The black screen is just
>   your window background as defined by your theme. There is a great
>   article [here](https://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/) by Cyril Mottier, an Android Developer Expert, on this
>   topic. You can customise this to look a little nicer as explained in
>   the article (basically just change your window background, but be wary
>   of overdraw)

Comment: Hi akshay tilekar thak you for your valuable respose, this project is phonegap project, not in android project your configuration based on android project, so please give solution for phonegap.i am using build for adope phonegap.

Comment: @sriram there is config file in phonegap also

Comment: try reading this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html

Comment: @sriram see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950261/how-to-avoid-black-screen-in-phonegap/41951414?noredirect=1#comment71082669_41951414

Comment: Hi akshay tilekar when i implement your code it's removed title bar,But the black screen is came again, so please give me a  some suggestion.Thanks for your response..

Comment: @sriram i have added the description in answer,check that out and if you are satisfied with answer then accept it and upvote,Thanks !!

Comment: i'm getting black screen again in my phone gap project please anybody resolve this problem.The above command only remove the title...

Comment: @sriram if you configure your xml,you will never get blank screen again.. try updating xml

Comment: i'm using cordova version 6.5.0 and phonegap version 6.4.3,when i create in project in cordova command and implement plugin also in cordova command and i build to the adobe phonegap build still i am facing the same problem